# How to use DataAccess to store Long Int map in GraphHopper

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, graphhopper

I found this :
https://github.com/karussell/graphhopper-osm-id-mapping/blob/master/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/osmidexample/MyGraphHopper.java

```
// Set
long pointer = 8L * edgeId;
edgeMapping.ensureCapacity(pointer + 8L);

edgeMapping.setInt(pointer, bitUtil.getIntLow(osmWayId));
edgeMapping.setInt(pointer + 4, bitUtil.getIntHigh(osmWayId));


// Get
long pointer = 8L * internalEdgeId;
return bitUtil.combineIntsToLong(edgeMapping.getInt(pointer), edgeMapping.getInt(pointer + 4L));
```

In this sample, it use DataAccess to store EdgeId(Int) -> OSMWayId(Long) mapping,
however I want to do it conversely, use OSMWayId(Long) as Key, EdgeId(Int) as Value and store it into DataAccess, but no idea how to, can anyone help ? thanks

Comment: As this is a duplicate this is answered here instead: https://discuss.graphhopper.com/t/how-to-use-dataaccess-to-store-long-int-map-in-graphhopper/624